# ASP net core MVC - Start Web application in a library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to start a web application, self hosted with Kestrel, from a console project. The web application is in a library.
I have a solution with two projects, i.e.:

- --APP.Console.exe (a dotnet core 3.1 console application)
- --APP.WebSite   (a dotnet core 3.1 class library)

The App.Console, calls an APP.WebSite singleton method to start the web app.
The solution compiles, but when the website starts, I got over 50 errors like this scren shots:
[image]

If I modify the APP.WebSite into a console Application, it regulary starts with no errors.
Where I'm wrong?

**EDIT1:**
Start console app:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        Test.Start.StartApp();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

StartApp static method:

```
    public static void  StartApp()
    {
        var s = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        //activate web hosting here            
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
              .UseKestrel(o =>
              {
                  o.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
                  o.ListenAnyIP(5000);
                  //o.ListenLocalhost(5000);
              })
              .UseWebRoot(s + "/Web/wwwroot")
              //.UseContentRoot(s+"/Web/wwwroot")
              .UseStartup<StartUpWeb>()
              .Build();

        host.Start();
    }
```

In Web/wwwroot there all client files

**EDIT2:** Solution folders:

[image]

Comment: We need to see all the code...We need to able to reproduce the problem.  Also starting a .NET Core website usually requires running dotnet command.  But it depends on what your code looks like

Comment: Also we need to know how you are publishing this app and how are you "starting" the app from the console.

Comment: No, not publishing, just debugging. The code is very simple. I'll try to edit the question.

Comment: It may be connected to location of views, location of the web root, and maybe also other things. Just a question, If the webSite project is working for you, why do you need a second project the console then?

Comment: @MartinStaufcik, I suppsosed id, but the error should be completely different. Moreover the view are placed into the corrcet folder. I need to separate desktop APP, Console APP and WEB App. The whole Application is a mix of them.

Comment: When I run it it works.  What is the folder structure?  Are views and controllers under Web/wwwroot or where?

Comment: One thing I noticed when debugging is that the content of Web folder is NOT copied to the Console.exe debug folder.... So I dont get styles and images but the rest of the website works.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro, Yes I copied everything. But in this case the error would hve been different. Views are under Web/Views

Comment: Where are controllers?  Also how do you "convert" to a class library?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro look at my last update. "Convert to class library"? You mean into the project properties? Yes of course.

Comment: I found the problems. I am going to post a solution.

Comment: Done! I have posted a comprehensive answer on how I was able to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to achieve what you want using .NET Core 3.1.1, but there is a few things I had to do.

**First** your folder structure is wrong.

The correct folder structure is this:

[image]

Notice I moved the wwwroot folder to a folder called Web... ONLY the wwwroot

**Second** The correct way to "convert" a asp.net core website to a class library is here:

[image]

So basically create a asp.net core web application project then right click properties and change the output type.

**Third** starting from a Class Library project
If you are starting from .NET Core Class Library Project then you can open the csproj file and change a few things :

This is how my csproj file looks like now:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <ApplicationIcon />
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <StartupObject />
    <EnableDefaultContentItems>true</EnableDefaultContentItems>  
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Web\wwwroot\**">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

So basically change the Sdk, the OutputType, EnableDefaultContentItems and add an ItemGroup to force copy all the content files for wwwroot.

**Finally**
Your code should look this:

```
        public static void StartApp(string environment)//notice the new parameter
        {
            var s = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            //activate web hosting here            
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                  .UseEnvironment(environment)//set the environment for debugging mostly
                  .UseKestrel(o =>
                  {
                      o.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
                      o.ListenAnyIP(5000);
                  //o.ListenLocalhost(5000);
                  })
                  .UseWebRoot(s + "\\Web\\wwwroot")//notice the correct path to client files
                  //.UseContentRoot(s+"/Web/wwwroot")
                  .UseStartup<StartUpWeb>()
                  .Build();

            host.Start();
        }
```

And your entry point in your Console App:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            Test.Start.StartApp("Development");//pass the environment for debugging

            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

I made a few changes to your code.

Specify the environment to debug and load configuration files etc....

Also specify the WebRoot to find stuff like client files and views(even though they are compiled it still needs a webroot).

Here is the result hooraay!!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You got it!
The very problem was this configuration line:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

Thank you Jonathan